# Fetching records into mutable POJO Jooq

Tags: jooq

I went through the documentation [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/) on fetching records into mutable pojo in Jooq.

It says that columns are mapped to the best matching constructor, attributes or setters.

Can anyone share more information what does best matching attributes or setter means?

How does it map the column when I am not using JPA annotation and my pojo has multiple attributes with same datatype?

Does it consider the column name or column ordering to map with attribute in pojo with same ordering or attribute name?

When transferring object into pojo, does it create the object of Record as well and then convert it into pojo or it creates directly pojo?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained in the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) Javadoc. The section that seems relevant to you is this (from jOOQ version 3.11):

> **If a default constructor is available and if there are no JPA Column annotations, or jOOQ can't find the javax.persistence API on the classpath, jOOQ will map Record values by naming convention:**
>
> If Field.getName() is MY_field (case-sensitive!), then this field's value will be set on all of these (regardless of visibility):
>
> - Single-argument instance method MY_field(...)
> - Single-argument instance method myField(...)
> - Single-argument instance method setMY_field(...)
> - Single-argument instance method setMyField(...)
> - Non-final instance member field MY_field
> - Non-final instance member field myField